# How to sync filesystem and wait until it's done

Tags: linux, usb, filesystems, sync

On my embedded device, I want to let user export logs on plugged USB disk. USB disk is normally used only to read, so I don't care much about safe unmounting. But when logs are stored to it, I need to sync it's filesystem to write all changes. Currently I have script which copy logs to USB and then call sync command, but synchronization is not performed immediately, user must wait some extra time after script finished. If he unplugs USB right after script finish, there are no logs written. Is there some way to force waiting until synchronization is finished? Or some way to check it?